# java.io.EOFException on FileOutputStream

Tags: java, arrays, fileinputstream, objectinputstream, eofexception

I have a class that reads the written output of a Student[] array object

here is the code

```
import java.io.*;

// I use this class to read the final ouput "students_updated.dat"
public class StudentArrayObjectFileReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream fileReader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("students_updated.dat"));
        Student[] studs = (Student[]) fileReader.readObject();
        fileReader.close();

        // List the records in console
        for (int i = 0; i < studs.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%7d %-35s %-5s %1d %-6s%n",studs[i].getID(), studs[i].getName(), studs[i].getCourse(), studs[i].getYr(), studs[i].getGender());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

problem is that it has an error when reading the `Student[] studs = (Student[]) fileReader.readObject();`

as stated here

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2571)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at StudentArrayObjectFileReader.main(StudentArrayObjectFileReader.java:9)
```

any idea on what could be the problem? Thanks in advance..

this is how the `students_updated.dat` was written

```
    public void saveStudentArray() { // studs print to student_updated.dat
    try{
        output.writeObject(studs); // write the final studs
        output.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

with its `ObjectInputStream` declared in the constructor of where this method is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the contents of the students_updated.dat file. readObject() function expects the file to contain a serialized object.

Does the file contain a serialized object? Check if the serialization succeeded without anything going wrong?

If you're trying to construct the array from a plain text file, you should not use readObject().

Visit this link for a sample of how to serialize and deserialize an array - [Can I serialize an array directly...](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=34789)

Comment: It was the fact that the object array was not serialized. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Move this line:

```
fileReader.close();
```

after your `for` loop.

In Java, the creation of a variable is simply creating a reference to some location in memory. The act of casting the object read from `fileReader` into your array of students just creates a pointer to the correct place in memory. If you then remove that place by closing the fileReader, you remove the location `studs` is pointing to.

Comment: it still returns the same exception. I also tried it without the `fileReader.close()` but not a chance of it working.

Comment: Are you sure your file has something in it? How is this data getting encoded?

Comment: yes there is a student[] in it, i used a `system.out.print();` to make appear in the console and it does have contents

Comment: that is before writing the object by the way